# Input in span (set position)

Tags: html, css

I want to replace the input border trouth an span border but i cant set the correct position for the input.

**span=Orange, input=Gray:**
[Image](http://i39.tinypic.com/xwy8g.png)

**CSS**

```
input[type=text]
{
    padding: 0px;
    outline: none; /*border: 0;*/
}

.mySpan
{
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid darkorange;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="mySpan">            
  <input id="myInput" type="text" value="SUP" />
</span>
```

Comment: border: none; on your input[type=text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
border:0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLLhY/